# Submit of simple HTML form with get method fails to construct URL with params

Tags: html, forms

I have the following simple HTML:

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Foo</title>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://example.com">
  <input type="hidden" id="go">
  <div>
    <label for="userid">Userid:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userid">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I validated this with W3C's online validator: all that it doesn't like is the `hidden` `input` element not being inside a `div`, `p` or some such.

When this page is loaded and the form is filled and submitted, it goes to the exact URL `http://example.com`, without any form parameters.

This happens whether I serve it as a static page from a server, output it out of a CGI script or access it as a local document using `file://...` on my desktop box. The behavior is the same using Firefox 43.0.4 on Windows 7, IE 11, or FF 42.0 on Ubuntu 12.

What is missing to make it produce something like `http://example.com?go&userid=whatever`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't use name attributes in input fields.

Comment: Ah, `name`, not `id`.

Comment: Man, I compared to other small examples, and to a big complex form in a working application I made previously and was still blind to this.